# Removing Log4j2.xml from Tranisitive Dependecies and to use Log4j2-spring.xml instead in springboot project

Tags: spring-boot, log4j2

I need to add file Appender in existing log4j2.xml of my existing spring-boot project. i did that and its generating two logs files for every logger specified i.e, i have only added Root level logger then also two files are getting generated.
When i searched for it i found that in spring projects log4j2-spring.xml should be used instead of Log4j2.xml which may be the cause of duplicates log files getting generated.

But when i am trying to run to change my log4j2.xml to log4j2-spring.xml its not even considering that file and is picking any other log4j2.xml that is available via classpath as i have added some external jar as dependency in this project the log4j2.xml of these exteranl dependemcies are being considered rather then my log4j2-spring.xml. Is there a way of telling it to use my log4j2-spring.xml instead of any log4j2.xml or may be is there a way to remove the usage of log4j2.xml from any dependency.

I tried doing the same with a simple spring-boot project and it worked as expected but when i am trying to do the same in my project which is multi-module maven project it does not works.

Can someone let me know what would be the way of doing above said asks.

Here is my pom.

`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="info" monitorInterval="60">
    <Properties>
        <Property name="log-path">${sys:app.log.path}</Property>
        <Property name="archive">${log-path}/archive</Property>
        <Property name="appName">${sys:spring.application.name}</Property>
        <Property name="envName">${sys:app.env.name}</Property>
    </Properties>
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="Console-Appender" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout>
                <pattern>
                    %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS}{GMT} [%-5level] [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n
                </pattern>
                <charset>US-ASCII</charset>
            </PatternLayout>
        </Console>
        <File name="File" fileName="${log-path}/${appName}-${envName}--${date:yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss-SSS}.log" append="true">
           <PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyyy-MMM-dd HH:mm:ss a} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n" />
       </File>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="INFO" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console-Appender" level="WARN" />
            <AppenderRef ref="File" level="INFO" />
        </Root>
        <Logger name="com.tmo.eus" level="INFO" additivity="false">
            <Appender-ref ref="Console-Appender" />
        </Logger>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

`

Comment: Please post your pom.xml so that others can help you.

Comment: We have a multi module maven project i can definately post one pom but it references multiple other project and dependencies so posting all the poms would not be easier.